# How can I export my Firestore database from a Google Storage Bucket into a Json file

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

Here's the situation: I have a Firestore Database. I download it on a daily basis to a Google Cloud Storage Bucket as a backup. If I want to download it locally, I do it using this command `gsutil -m cp -r gs://BUCKET_PATH "DESTINATION_PATH"` and it works fine.

**MY PROBLEM**: the format of the Bucket I download is LevelDB (I think). On my machine, it looks like this :

[image]

For example, this is my `/users` collection in Firestore when I download it through Google Storage. In the folder, I have multiple binary files ("output-...") and a file ( here: "all_namespaces_kind_users") for metadata.

**MY GOAL**: I want to be able to read my database in a json file.

**MY TRIES**:

- I try to use this convertor : https://github.com/Venryx/firestore-leveldb-tools but it uses Python2 and some old google libraries. Using this convertor, I have to download the SDKs locally (see below).

```py
#repoRoot = os.getcwd()
repoRoot = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# import google sdks
sys.path.append(os.path.join(repoRoot, 'SDKs/google_appengine'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(repoRoot, 'SDKs/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party'))
from google.appengine.api.files import records
from google.appengine.datastore import entity_pb
from google.appengine.api import datastore
```

- Using the precedent convertor, I tried updating it to Python3, using these recommandations : https://github.com/Venryx/firestore-leveldb-tools/issues/1#issuecomment-674563473. I succeed to replace the first import `from google.appengine.api.files import records` but not the two others.
- For the two others : `from google.appengine.datastore import entity_pb` and `from google.appengine.api import datastore`, I saw this : https://pypi.org/project/protobuf-cloud-datastore-translator/ but I dont understand it fully.

**MY QUESTION**: How can I convert my Firestore Database (stored in a Google Bucket) to a json file ?
Maybe someone has a complete different approach to propose ? Or should I stick to my way ? In that case, how can I finish to translate the convertor to Python3 using updated google librairies ?

**BONUS QUESTION**: How the h**l does not Google has a clean solution for that ? (or am I stupid?)

Comment: What command or recipe are you using to backup the database?

Comment: I'm using a Cloud function and Google Cloud Scheduler to call the function everyday. I took the same Cloud function as written here : https://medium.com/swlh/backup-firestore-data-to-storage-bucket-on-a-schedule-in-gcp-7d910b2dea70 (under index.js)

Comment: Hello, a good option could be that in your cloud function each time that you made a backcup to your bucket at the same time you export your database to json format using [node-firebase-import-export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firestore-import-export) (check the section exporting) and then you send it to save in other place.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem? I have the feeling Google makes this as painful as possible to get to your data to bind you their services

Comment: Just check the accepted solution. Works pretty well (except for subcollections).

Comment: gsutil no longer maintained, went with
 gcloud storage cp -r gs://...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a converter in Python 3 which could convert firestore export files into JSON files [firestore-export-json](https://github.com/labbots/firestore-export-json). The package provides a simple CLI command to covert the file.

```
fs_to_json [path_to_source_dir] -d [path_to_destination]
```

Comment: I tested your script and add a pull request to it. I also found an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately as of today this still doesn't work with a full backup, just with single collections

Comment: @Patric amazing tool, thanks a ton!! I was also successful in running it per-collection. Cheers